# Google Finance API in JavaScript or Python to get Currency exchange rate

Tags: position, gdata, portfolio, google-finance

I am looking to find a API that I can use in ***JavaScript or Python to be able to eXchange the currency rates.*
I need the example of using those APIs too.** 
Do you Guys have any Idea how to find it ?
**JavaScript or Python 
portfolio and positions example ?**

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-using-google-finance-api ??

Comment: No It is not. the should be a way to get currency from google api as stocks. that q is just suggest to use somewhere else ..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the current exchange rate, you can use the Yahoo finance API (`http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDINR=X`).

For retrieving the exchange rate of a currency relative to USD for a particular historical date, you can use the Yahoo currency-converter-cache API (`http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date=<YYYYMMDD>`).

I made this simple currency converter module that uses Yahoo Finance API and supports historical date. https://github.com/iqbalhusen/currency_converter.

Comment: @DJClayworth Thanks. I have edited my answer to include the essential parts.

Answer (score 2):

Just try [CurrencyFreaks API](https://currencyfreaks.com/). It provides the latest currency exchange for 179 currencies worldwide in JSON/XML formats compatible with various programming languages including Javascript and PHP.

**Currency conversion by using Javascript:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest/convert
    ?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY
    &from=USD&to=EUR
    &amount=500");

xhr.send();
```

The JSON response will be:

```
{
    "date": "2020-10-16 15:08:00+00",
    "current_rates": {
        "USD": "1.0",
        "EUR": "0.8533"
    },
    "converted_amount": "426.6215",
    "query": {
        "given_amount": "500.0",
        "from": "USD",
        "to": "EUR"
    }
}
```

**Currency conversion by using PHP:**

```
setUrl('https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest/convert
    ?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY
    &from=USD&to=EUR
    &amount=500');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$request->setConfig(array(
  'follow_redirects' => TRUE
));
try {
  $response = $request->send();
  if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
    echo $response->getBody();
  }
  else {
    echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
    $response->getReasonPhrase();
  }
}
catch(HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The JSON response will be the same.

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The link of finance.yahoo.com is not working !

One can use : 
http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y