# API for Currency Converter and Generating a List of Different Currency across the World

Tags: ios

Would any one let me know whether or not, we have an **API** for **Currency Converting**. I can't convert it mathematically because the currency rates changes too frequently.So probably i need to parse some string.It would be great if you come up with some cool ideas to do the same.
Also i need an **API** which would generate a **list of Different Currencies'** across the World,as of-course, I **cannot** use an **array** to populate the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a list of currencies is trivial:

```
NSArray* currencyISOCodes = [NSLocale commonISOCurrencyCodes]
...
NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString* currencyName = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode
                                             value:currencyISOcode];
```

Currencies don't change often and the list will be updated with new iOS system update.

Currency conversion is not trivial but there are MANY free server APIs you can use, e.g. Google Finance API ([How do I get currency exchange rates via an API such as Google Finance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-using-google-finance-api)).

Comment: Sulthan :That was quick, Friend. Anyways I need to check if it's working right to Accept your answer.

Comment: Sulthan : When i browsed google i found this link but it is not possible to parse it as it show's this is invalid string when i used it in online JSON viewer.               http://www.google.com/finance/converter

Comment: @MohammedNaveedShaikh Look at the SO link I posted. The first answer shows how to use the converter API.

Comment: Sulthan : That worked for me. Thank You So much for getting me an answer soo soon.