# rate exchange currency converter error

Tags: php, json, api, currency

I do not have coding related problem here. I want some details about currency converter API.

```
$l_json_from = $this->currency->format($total_row['value'], false, false, false);
$l_url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=INR&to=USD&q=$l_json_from";
$l_jsons = @file_get_contents($l_url);
$l_json_data = json_decode($l_jsons, true);
$l_to_cur = $l_json_data['v'];
```

I have used this above code to convert the INR rate into USD rate using [this URL](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com). Yesterday it’s working fine. But, today it doesn't work. Rate exchange API URL says:

> Over Quota
>
> This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later.

Why this site shows like this? What is the reason? Shall I try any other currency Converter API?

Answer (score 0):

> Over Quota
>
> This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try
>   again later.

It means that the host (Google App Engine?) serving [`rate-exchange.appspot.com`](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com) is over quota. Which means you cannot use it until the owners of the API (who I believe [are these folks](http://currency-api.appspot.com)) solve the issue on their side.

But there are many more similar currency exchange APIs available as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391430/117259).