# Using currency rates in a mobile app

Tags: android, currency, mobile-application

I am using Android Studio in order to build a sample of a mobile banking app. In this mobile application, I need to transfer amounts of money from one account to the other. At some point, if the accounts have different currencies, I need to convert the amount to be transferred to the amount that corresponds with the currency needed. For example, if I am transferring 200$ from one account to another in euros, I need to multiply that amount with the rate of the receiving account just like this: 200*1.13=226€. For now, I have been using  default values for the rates. The tricky part is that currency rates are constantly changing so I need to keep it up to date. I suppose that I should retrieve the information I need from another source like a website, but I have no idea how to do so. Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the European Central Bank free API to get a daily update. You can find it [here](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) in xml format

Answer (score -1):

You can use currency convertor api's. For eg:

http://jsonrates.com/docs/

Get your API key, and pass in this url along with the currencies

Request: `http://jsonrates.com/get/?from=USD&to=EUR&apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY`

Response:

```
 {
  "utctime": "2014-06-26T15:00:03+02:00",
  "from": "USD",
  "to": "EUR",
  "rate": "0.73514500"
}
```

Comment: or else refer to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance