# Append daily exchange rates to Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, currency-exchange-rates

I have a dataset like:

```
a = DataFrame({'clicks': {0: 12, 1: 19, 2: 14},
               'country ': {0: 'norway', 1: 'sweden', 2: 'italy'},
                 'date': {0: '2/2/2016', 1: '2/3/2016', 2: '2/4/2016'}})
```

I would like to add a new column to `a`, in order to get the exchange rates to Euro for those countries, looking like:

```
a = DataFrame({'clicks': {0: 12, 1: 19, 2: 14},
               'country ': {0: 'norway', 1: 'sweden', 2: 'italy'},
               'date': {0: '2/2/2016', 1: '2/3/2016', 2: '2/4/2016'},
               'exchangerate': {0: 0.92400000000000004, 1: 0.91700000000000004, 2: 1.0}})
```

I was thinking about using:

```
import pandas.io.data as web

jp = web.DataReader('DEXJPUS', 'fred')
```

but I can't find anything about EUR and other European currencies + linking to my df and getting daily data.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance

Comment: Check out `Quandl` if you do not find desired FX rates at Yahoo! or Google

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov its a very useful resource but I dont manage to find euro vs. other european currencies either in FRED or Quandl

Comment: Would you please give an exact list of what you mean by `EUR and other European currencies` crossrates? Because in your example I see Italy. Don't they have EUR as their currency???