# C# String.Format doesn't place a variable in the respective placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got some code in here that getting world currency exchanges from net. But in following code, this line

```
private double GetConvertedCurrencyValue(string inputCurrency, string outputCurrency, double value) 
{
    string request = String.Format("http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount={0}&From={1}&To={2}", value, inputCurrency, outputCurrency);

    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string apiResponse = wc.DownloadString(request);    // This is a blocking operation.
    wc.Dispose();


    string header = String.Format("XE.com: {0} to {2} rate:",inputCurrency, outputCurrency);


    apiResponse = apiResponse.Replace(header, "");


    string outValue = apiResponse.Split('=')[1];


    outValue = outValue.Replace(outputCurrency, "");

    return Double.Parse(outValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

was error. What can I do?

Comment: Please add the error

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code you have:

```
string header = String.Format("XE.com: {0} to {2} rate:",inputCurrency, outputCurrency);
```

It should be:

```
string header = String.Format("XE.com: {0} to {1} rate:",inputCurrency, outputCurrency);
```

Comment: thank you but now it is error - return Double.Parse(outValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: What error are you getting? You need you specify the error so the community can help you.

Comment: It gave me "Input string is not correct format". If you have another code for this solution please share.

Comment: This Means that whatever is in  `outValue` is not compatible to be Convert to a double. Put a breakpoint on `string outValue = apiResponse.Split('=')[0];` and step through it and you will see what I mean. make sure you are parsing the API response correctly or have the right permissions?

Comment: I just want such a method that gets data from internet. For example https://en.cbar.az/other/azn-rates?act=fetchForm&date%5Bday%5D=2&date%5Bmonth%5D=10&date%5Byear%5D=2017 from this link for exchanges

Comment: Check out [Matthiee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43573923/5326036) answer. It might be useful.