# Yahoo finance library - get list of FTSE 100 companies

Tags: java, yahoo-finance, stocks

Is there a way to get the list of the entire current FTSE 100 companies using Yahoo finance in Java, perhaps into a String or an array?

Comment: Yahoo finance API is only able to retrieve the current quote of a given stock index or symbol. If you want to retrieve the quote of every company in FTSE 100, you would need to do chain all of the symbols in you API call. [See here](http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/)

Comment: So I have to manually type in the symbols?

Comment: Yes you have. Yahoo finance API status is unclear, a part of it has been discontinued, those are all the [possible alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance?noredirect=1&lq=1).