# All Currencies with base currency KWD in Yahoo finance

Tags: c#, json, currency-exchange-rates

I have a requirement in my application to fetch the currencies conversion rates on a daily basis with a Base Currency KWD . I have checked Yahoo finance ( and few other free providers) for the same. But yahoo shows default base currency as USD or need currency pairs( basecurrency-convertingcurrecy) format. 
For example :

```
`https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json`
```

( all currencies with default base currency USD - can we change this? )
then other option like having pairs as below using YQL in console ,
select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDKWD,GBPKWD") 
which generates a url like

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDMXN%22%2C%22KWDUSD%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

which is a clumsy url . 
Do we have any options to fetch All the currency rates with KWD as base currency.

One more option I had checked is which looks pretty handy but don't know whether the base currency can be changed in the free version and whether it supports all currencies . 
Appreciate any thoughts shared on regarding the same. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it using Yahoo Finance only then using YQL is the only way, so you'll end up with something like this:

[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("KWDEUR", "KWDJPY", "KWDBGN", "KWDCZK", "KWDDKK", "KWDGBP", "KWDHUF", "KWDLTL", "KWDLVL", "KWDPLN", "KWDRON", "KWDSEK", "KWDCHF", "KWDNOK", "KWDHRK", "KWDRUB", "KWDTRY", "KWDAUD", "KWDBRL", "KWDCAD", "KWDCNY", "KWDHKD", "KWDIDR", "KWDILS", "KWDINR", "KWDKRW", "KWDMXN", "KWDMYR", "KWDNZD", "KWDPHP", "KWDSGD", "KWDTHB", "KWDZAR", "KWDISK", "KWDUSD")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22KWDEUR%22,%20%22KWDJPY%22,%20%22KWDBGN%22,%20%22KWDCZK%22,%20%22KWDDKK%22,%20%22KWDGBP%22,%20%22KWDHUF%22,%20%22KWDLTL%22,%20%22KWDLVL%22,%20%22KWDPLN%22,%20%22KWDRON%22,%20%22KWDSEK%22,%20%22KWDCHF%22,%20%22KWDNOK%22,%20%22KWDHRK%22,%20%22KWDRUB%22,%20%22KWDTRY%22,%20%22KWDAUD%22,%20%22KWDBRL%22,%20%22KWDCAD%22,%20%22KWDCNY%22,%20%22KWDHKD%22,%20%22KWDIDR%22,%20%22KWDILS%22,%20%22KWDINR%22,%20%22KWDKRW%22,%20%22KWDMXN%22,%20%22KWDMYR%22,%20%22KWDNZD%22,%20%22KWDPHP%22,%20%22KWDSGD%22,%20%22KWDTHB%22,%20%22KWDZAR%22,%20%22KWDISK%22,%20%22KWDUSD%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

The [terms](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html) allow usage of 2000 requests per hour per IP so if you are targetting more than that then you'll have to request an API key.

Do check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391430/1186936) out for a community curated list of alternate paid and free APIs available.

[Fixer.io API](http://fixer.io/) is a free one too but it doesn't support KWD as a base.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have missed the answer posted by you.

Comment: @user2695433 No worries. If the answer helped you out, you can still upvote it or mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: accepted your answer and upvoted . thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using YQL like this `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20("USDKWD%2CEURKWD%2CGBPKWD%2CAEDKWD%2CAFNKWD%2CALLKWD%2CAMDKWD%2CANGKWD%2CAUDKWD%2CBDTKWD%2CBGNKWD%2CBHDKWD%2CBNDKWD%2CBOBKWD%2CBSDKWD%2CBTNKWD%2CBYNKWD%2CCADKWD%2CCHFKWD%2CCLPKWD%2CCNYKWD%2CCOPKWD%2CCRCKWD%2CCUPKWD%2CDKKKWD%2CDOPKWD%2CDZPKWD%2CEGPKWD%2CGELKWD%2CHKDKWD%2CHRKKWD%2CHUFKWD%2CIDRKWD%2CILSKWD%2CINRKWD%2CIQDKWD%2CIRRKWD%2CISKKWD%2CJODKWD%2CJPYKWD%2CKGSKWD%2CKHRKWD%2CKPWKWD%2CKRWKWD%2CKWDKWD%2CKZTKWD%2CLBPKWD%2CLKRKWD%2CMNTKWD%2CMURKWD%2CMXNKWD%2CNGNKWD%2CNZDKWD%2COMRKWD%2CPENKWD%2CPHPKWD%2CPKRKWD%2CPLNKWD%2CPYGKWD%2CQARKWD%2CRONKWD%2CRUBKWD%2CSARKWD%2CSDGKWD%2CSEKKWD%2CSGDKWD%2CSYPKWD%2CTHBKWD%2CTRYKWD%2CTTDKWD%2CTWDKWD%2CUAHKWD%2CUZSKWD%2CYERKWD%2CZARKWD")&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys`

The above url is autogenerated on executing the YQL statement. 
fixer.io doesn't have KWD as base currency too so that is not even an option.