# How make PayPal support to currency which were not listed in support?

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I was trying to integrate the PayPal in iOS as well as Android native application for in India & Qatar, which currencies are INR & QAR, As much i know PayPal does not support such Currency so is there only option to use currency convertor?

If yes, can anybody tell me how can i achieve it step by step.

Comment: I guess there is no default currency or payment which uses INR and QAR at the moment in PayPal. You'd have to use USD or any other available types to make payment.

Comment: Yes you are correct do you know any well know open source API for currency conversion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any API regarding that. You may have to Google to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PayPal does not support yet lot of currencies. [See supported currency code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/).

Anyway if you want to achieve thing you must need to use currency convertor you can use Google API or Yahoo API for that.

You can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3139879/4294543) & you can talk with your backend developer regarding this he will assist you even better & easy way,

I have used it once in **Android native app** Yahoo exchange rates like,

**Step 1:**

```
private String fromCurrency = "QAR";
private String toCurrency = "USD";

private String urlString = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3D" + fromCurrency + toCurrency + "%3DX%22%3B&format=json";
```

**Step 2:**

```
 private void apiCallCurrencyConversion() {

        //Don't mind you can you retrofit call too,

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlString)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    }
                });
                if (response.code() == 200 && response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final CurrencyYahooApiJSON currencyYahooApiJSON = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), CurrencyYahooApiJSON.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, currencyYahooApiJSON.getQuery().getResults().getRow().getConvertedValue());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            proceedToPay(currencyYahooApiJSON);

                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

You can download the ResponseJsonObject pojo from [here](https://github.com/mukeshlokare/PayPalIntegration)

Now you are ready to use the converted value with **USD**,

**Step 3:**

```
private void proceedToPay(CurrencyYahooApiJSON currencyYahooApiJSON) {
        //Getting the amount from editText
         String paymentAmount = "100";    

        Row row = currencyYahooApiJSON.getQuery().getResults().getRow();

        double val = Double.valueOf(paymentAmount);
        double convertedAmount = val * Double.valueOf(row.getConvertedValue());

        // convertedAmount here will us get is near about 27.41
       //PayPal Configuration & payment process ahead.
}
```

**Cheers**

Comment: **works great** but what the assurance of API it not will affect anything in future?

Comment: Alright since i am using 2 year, it is working properly for more info you can visit [here](http://www.codereye.com/2009/03/java-currency-converter-using-yahoo.html)