# Stripe payment multiple currency

Tags: php, stripe-payments, currency

I have implemented stripe payment using php. The base currency is Euro. how can i add option to allow the user to pay in another currencies

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => $amount, 
"currency" => "eur", 
"source" => $source,
"customer" => "cus_BpES3vz708LAn3"
"description" => $description 
));
```

many thanks

Comment: post your code also

Comment: @GyandeepSharma   I checked some options in this link. but couldn't find a method to convert currency

Comment: @AnandhuNadesh please check

Comment: You need an API for this Check this link - http://www.phpzag.com/convert-currency-using-google-api/

Answer (score 1):

Stripe can process charges in basically [any currency](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies) you want, but at the moment it does not have an API for converting amounts. It'd be up to you to compute the converted amount, e.g. using a [third-party API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391430/5307473), and pass the correct `amount` and `currency` parameters to Stripe when [creating the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).