# Rails product database with different currency/pricing

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, currency

I have a product table in my Rails application with following columns:

```
table "products"
t.string   "name"
t.text     "description"
t.integer  "price"
```

When I was developing the app, it was just for a single country and for single currency. Now I would like to support more currencies based on geo country but what is the best way to do it with my current database structure?

It was recommended to me to use Money gem but it is just money exchange. What I really want is to set up manually different pricing for different currencies/countries.

Any recommendation on the best way to do it?

Update: We don't plan to have more than like 20 products and our pricing is a bit higher so we don't care about the exchange rate - rather we would like to have different pricing based on how strong is the economy in certain countries

Comment: I suggest you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance if you mind exchange rates.

Comment: Or set maybe set up a table with `product_id | currency_id | price`, but becomes a big deal to keep update if you have a lot of products and currencies.

Comment: @iGian thank you for the idea.. I like the product_id | currency_id | price... you could describe it in detail in the answer section and I will mark it as the correct answer if you don't mind

Comment: Why not? Hope the answer could help. Or back in touch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up to my comment, I should use the join table `prices` between `products` and `currencies`, with an [the has_many :through Association](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), like shown in documentation.

The join model `Price` has columns:

```
| product_id | currency_id | value |
```

`Price` relations:

```
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :currency
end
```

Of course, the model `Currency` is required, which can store, name, country, symbol, flag, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try Globalize gem for content need supporting multi languages/regions/currencies.
https://github.com/globalize/globalize

Comment: This seems to do only I18n. The problem here is bigger than that.