# Google currency converter API - will it shut down with iGoogle?

Tags: currency, igoogle

iGoogle is [shutting down](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2664197?hl=en).

There is an (undocumented?) currency conversion API available with URLs like:
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1GBP=?USD

The base of this url - google.com/ig - takes you to iGoogle. Will the API be available after iGoogle shuts down?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was having the same issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19786423/2819754

I used @hobailey answer for a temporary fix until i can update it to another version or google decide to do a proper api.

As google changed the URL to

```
  https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a
```

So the fix i found is below.

```
  $amount = urlencode($amount);
  $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
  $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
  $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
  $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
  $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);  
  $converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
```

thanks to @hobailey for this little fix.

Comment: https://www.google.com/finance/convertera=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency - I believe there needs to be a "?" after "converter" for this to work.

Comment: @AaronFisher That link is dead.

Comment: @adamj This should work: https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=10&from=USD&to=GBP ('a' is the amount)

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can use following:

- http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=CAD&to=USD
- **http://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate?from=CAD&to=USD**

But the first one is not that stable goes out of capacity very often. We had an extreme problem in our production environment using the first exchange service few months back. So far second one is stable, doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: So, far I am using it in 6 - 7 live deployments with no issues. Also as far as we know there should not be chance to be closed.

Comment: Sougata Pal, is second one reliable ? Is there any chance that they shut it down anytime in future ?

Comment: well, no chance. I hope so.

Comment: @SougataPal All those links are dead now.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>iGoogle has already expired but not the gadget link you have posted. Currently it returns `200 OK` with probably your desired message.</strike>

<strike>**Update:**</strike> It got expired too. <strike>No Gadgets are available at the moment.</strike>

**Update:** Available from here https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=16.6700&from=GBP&to=USD

Comment: Thx! Google APIs are pretty fly-by-night it seems! (e.g. Reader, although that was never official too)

Comment: It seems the gadget is retired now. I get a response error now

Comment: I am having same issue. they have changed the url to http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=16.6700&from=GBP&to=USD so.  But i cannot get the response i need anymore from this so trying to work it out.

Comment: Thanks, the last one still works.. And if you go to the page on your browser , there's 1 text box (input) , 2 combo-boxes, and a submit button..

Comment: Appears that google.com/finance/converter is now also shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Free Currency Converter API from http://mycurrency.net

- It is 100% Free.
- No API key is required!
- No cap on frequency of API calls.
- Currency price is updated every two hours.
- Support json format.
- Very fast and reliable.
- The api address is here. It returns 176 currencies prices together with country name, country code, currency name and currency price. The base currency is USD.

  http://www.mycurrency.net/service/rates

There is also Free country flag API you may also need. Just replace the country code.

```
http://caches.space/flags/{countrycode}.png
```

Example:

http://caches.space/flags/sg.png [image: sg]

http://caches.space/flags/us.png [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use this URL

```
https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=INR
```

Replace

```
 https://www.google.com/finance/
```

to

```
https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/
```