# How to pass indian rupees value to paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, currency

How to convert indian rupees into USD value before to send to paypal? I am doing e-commerce site for indian client for this case wheteher i want to convert the indian rupees into USD value? Any solution for this?

Comment: Check out this answer i think so it will helpful to you.<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181990/programmatically-access-currency-exchange-rates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a currency conversion webservice such as [this one](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL) before sending the value to PayPal. For more info on consuming webservices, you need to specify your programming language.

The link to the webservice is just a sample one I found using Google, there will be plenty of them if you search for [Currency Conversion Web Service](http://www.google.com/search?q=currency%20conversion%20web%20service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: How can I use your idea for my requirement  : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/186198/51361

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically get converted to your primary currency when someone makes a payment.