# Currency conversion api using php

Tags: php, api, currency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically access currency exchange rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181990/programmatically-access-currency-exchange-rates)

Is there any api which provide exact converted value of currency? I have used google and yahoo api but they are not giving required result for VND(Vietnamese dong) to US dollars.

Comment: In case you're still looking - have a look at https://currencylayer.com

Answer (score 2):

How's this ?

```
<?php

$amount = urlencode("1");
$from_Currency = urlencode("VND");
$to_Currency = urlencode("USD");
$url = "hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency%3D%3F$to_Currency";
$rawdata = file_get_contents("http://google.com/ig/calculator?".$url);
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
$data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
$var = $data['0'];
echo $var;

?>
```

Comment: am using this only but it is returning the result as 4.8 but the actual value is 0.00004 it is not giving 10pow-5

Comment: i have also tried this ---                                      $from   = 'VND';
$to     = 'USD';
$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X';
$handle = @fopen($url, 'r');

if ($handle) {
    $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
    fclose($handle);
}
$allData = explode(',',$result); /* Get all the contents to an array */
$dollarValue = $allData[1];

echo 'Value of 1VND in USD is $. '.$dollarValue; -- it giving the ouput as 0.00

Comment: Hmm. If you just echo out $rawdata and remove the rest of the code, you will get this output: {lhs: "1 Vietnamese dong",rhs: "4.8 \x26#215; 10\x3csup\x3e-5\x3c/sup\x3e U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true} - Maybe you could try stripping this down using a regular expression or just use PHP's explode method to get the output you need?

Comment: The value will be in the format of 4.8e-5 but I need it as 0.000048. I couldn't able to convert that.