# Get Historic Data of currency exchange

Tags: json, xml, csv, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I want to get the Historic data of Currency exchange, I have tried running [this Query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%20in%20(%22EURUSD%3DX%22)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222015-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%222015-06-01%22&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env) on Yahoo console but it wont work.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol  in ("EURUSD=X") and startDate = "2015-06-01" and endDate ="2015-06-02"
```

Is it something that I'm doing wrong? Or is it not possible in Yahoo API?

Any other suggestion that you can give please?

Please note that I want historic data, not the current exchange rate.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114754/programmatically-access-currency-exchange-rates-from-yahoo-finance-by-date) post ?

Comment: Thanks for that link. As per my research I think there is no free API available for historic currency data. So will have to make use of paid API.