# A simple way to show 5-6 currency rates/converts?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, currency

I'm looking for a way to show a simple table with 5-6 currency rates. Just a simple code to show how much 1 USD is in EUR, NOK, DKK, GBP etc...

Does anyone have a good way to solve this?

[SOLVED] I found a good solution here if anyone need this in the future:
http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/#more-285

Here is how I used it:

```
<?php
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
$data = explode('"', $data['3']);
$var = $data['0'];
return round($var,1);
}
?>

<strong>Results:</strong><br />
100NOK to USD = <?php echo currency("NOK","USD",100); ?><br />
100NOK to EUR = <?php echo currency("NOK","EUR",100); ?><br />
100NOK to GBP = <?php echo currency("NOK","GBP",100); ?><br />
100NOK to SEK = <?php echo currency("NOK","SEK",100); ?><br />
100NOK to DKK = <?php echo currency("NOK","DKK",100); ?><br />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181990/programmatically-access-currency-exchange-rates?rq=1

Comment: alot of wordpress plugins, forex-box, but they are all lacking a way to setup your own currencys or a way to adjust the design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use Google's Currency converter

Here is a start point:

```
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?EUR
```

Comment: looks interesting, but how can I extract data in to html? I'm a bit new to it

Comment: it's json, use `json_decode()`

Comment: i found a solution - http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/#more-285