# How to do *USD to INR* currency conversion on-the-fly? - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, payment-gateway, woocommerce, ccavenue

Our store's base currency is USD & we're using PayPal for international customers. We want to use ccAvenue (INR) as the payment gateway for Indian customers. Unfortunately, ccAvenue does not read currency. So $12 would be pushed out from our website and ccAvenue would read it as INR 12 instead of the correct amount ~INR 600.

How can the amount be converted on-the-fly (from USD to INR) so that our website sends the correct amount to ccAvenue? Preferably this should be done within the plugin using a real-time currency conversion service. But, we're open to crude workarounds - like manually updating the conversion rate twice a week, etc. Here's the link to the [free ccavenue woocommerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ccavenue-payment-gateway-woocommerce/).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the index.php of the plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce CCAvenue gateway
Plugin URI: http://mrova.com/
Description: Extends WooCommerce with mrova ccavenue gateway.
Version: 1.1
Author: mRova
Author URI: http://mrova.com/

    Copyright: © 2009-2012 mRova.
    License: GNU General Public License v3.0
    License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_mrova_ccave_init', 0);

function woocommerce_mrova_ccave_init() {

    if ( !class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) ) return;

    /**
     * Localisation
     */
    load_plugin_textdomain('wc-mrova-ccave', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages');

    /**
     * Gateway class
     */
    class WC_Mrova_Ccave extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
    protected $msg = array();
        public function __construct(){
            // Go wild in here
            $this -> id = 'ccavenue';
            $this -> method_title = __('CCAvenue', 'mrova');
            $this -> icon = WP_PLUGIN_URL . "/" . plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/images/logo.gif';
            $this -> has_fields = false;
            $this -> init_form_fields();
            $this -> init_settings();
            $this -> title = $this -> settings['title'];
            $this -> description = $this -> settings['description'];
            $this -> merchant_id = $this -> settings['merchant_id'];
            $this -> working_key = $this -> settings['working_key'];
            $this -> redirect_page_id = $this -> settings['redirect_page_id'];
            $this -> liveurl = 'https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp';
            $this -> msg['message'] = "";
            $this -> msg['class'] = "";
            add_action('init', array(&$this, 'check_ccavenue_response'));
            add_action('valid-ccavenue-request', array(&$this, 'successful_request'));
            add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array(&$this, 'process_admin_options'));
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_ccavenue', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'));
            add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_ccavenue',array(&$this, 'thankyou_page'));
        }

        function init_form_fields(){

            $this -> form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title' => __('Enable/Disable', 'mrova'),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __('Enable CCAvenue Payment Module.', 'mrova'),
                    'default' => 'no'),
                'title' => array(
                    'title' => __('Title:', 'mrova'),
                    'type'=> 'text',
                    'description' => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'mrova'),
                    'default' => __('CCAvenue', 'mrova')),
                'description' => array(
                    'title' => __('Description:', 'mrova'),
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __('This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.', 'mrova'),
                    'default' => __('Pay securely by Credit or Debit card or internet banking through CCAvenue Secure Servers.', 'mrova')),
                'merchant_id' => array(
                    'title' => __('Merchant ID', 'mrova'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'description' => __('This id(USER ID) available at "Generate Working Key" of "Settings and Options at CCAvenue."')),
                'working_key' => array(
                    'title' => __('Working Key', 'mrova'),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'description' =>  __('Given to Merchant by CCAvenue', 'mrova'),
                ),
                'redirect_page_id' => array(
                    'title' => __('Return Page'),
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => $this -> get_pages('Select Page'),
                    'description' => "URL of success page"
                )
            );


        }
        /**
         * Admin Panel Options
         * - Options for bits like 'title' and availability on a country-by-country basis
         **/
        public function admin_options(){
            echo '<h3>'.__('CCAvenue Payment Gateway', 'mrova').'</h3>';
            echo '<p>'.__('CCAvenue is most popular payment gateway for online shopping in India').'</p>';
            echo '<table class="form-table">';
            $this -> generate_settings_html();
            echo '</table>';

        }
        /**
         *  There are no payment fields for CCAvenue, but we want to show the description if set.
         **/
        function payment_fields(){
            if($this -> description) echo wpautop(wptexturize($this -> description));
        }
        /**
         * Receipt Page
         **/
        function receipt_page($order){
            echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with CCAvenue.', 'mrova').'</p>';
            echo $this -> generate_ccavenue_form($order);
        }
        /**
         * Process the payment and return the result
         **/
        function process_payment($order_id){
            $order = &new woocommerce_order($order_id);
            return array('result' => 'success', 'redirect' => add_query_arg('order',
                $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_pay_page_id'))))
            );
        }
        /**
         * Check for valid CCAvenue server callback
         **/
        function check_ccavenue_response(){
            global $woocommerce;
            if(isset($_REQUEST['Order_Id']) && isset($_REQUEST['AuthDesc'])){
                $order_id_time = $_REQUEST['Order_Id'];
                $order_id = explode('_', $_REQUEST['Order_Id']);
                $order_id = (int)$order_id[0];
                if($order_id != ''){
                    try{
                        $order = new woocommerce_order($order_id);
                        $merchant_id = $_REQUEST['Merchant_Id'];
                        $amount = $_REQUEST['Amount'];
                        $checksum = $_REQUEST['Checksum'];
                        $AuthDesc = $_REQUEST['AuthDesc'];
                        $Checksum = $this -> verifyCheckSum($merchant_id, $order_id_time, $amount, $AuthDesc, $checksum, $this -> working_key);
                        $transauthorised = false;
                        if($order -> status !=='completed'){
                            if($Checksum=="true")
                            {

                                if($AuthDesc=="Y"){
                                    $transauthorised = true;
                                    $this -> msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. Your account has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon.";
                                    $this -> msg['class'] = 'success';
                                    if($order -> status == 'processing'){

                                    }else{
                                        $order -> payment_complete();
                                        $order -> add_order_note('CCAvenue payment successful<br/>Bank Ref Number: '.$_REQUEST['nb_bid']);
                                        $order -> add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
                                        $woocommerce -> cart -> empty_cart();

                                    }

                                }else if($AuthDesc=="B"){
                                    $this -> msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. We will keep you posted regarding the status of your order through e-mail";
                                    $this -> msg['class'] = 'info';

                                    //Here you need to put in the routines/e-mail for a  "Batch Processing" order
                                    //This is only if payment for this transaction has been made by an American Express Card
                                    //since American Express authorisation status is available only after 5-6 hours by mail from ccavenue and at the "View Pending Orders"
                                }
                                else{
                                    $this -> msg['class'] = 'error';
                                    $this -> msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. However, the transaction has been declined.";
                                    //Here you need to put in the routines for a failed
                                    //transaction such as sending an email to customer
                                    //setting database status etc etc
                                }
                            }else{
                                $this -> msg['class'] = 'error';
                                $this -> msg['message'] = "Security Error. Illegal access detected";

                                //Here you need to simply ignore this and dont need
                                //to perform any operation in this condition
                            }
                            if($transauthorised==false){
                                $order -> update_status('failed');
                                $order -> add_order_note('Failed');
                                $order -> add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
                            }
                            add_action('the_content', array(&$this, 'showMessage'));
                        }}catch(Exception $e){
                            // $errorOccurred = true;
                            $msg = "Error";
                        }

                }



            }



        }
        function showMessage($content){
            return '<div class="box '.$this -> msg['class'].'-box">'.$this -> msg['message'].'</div>'.$content;
        }
        /**
         * Generate CCAvenue button link
         **/
        public function generate_ccavenue_form($order_id){
            global $woocommerce;
            $order = &new woocommerce_order($order_id);
            $redirect_url = ($this -> redirect_page_id=="" || $this -> redirect_page_id==0)?get_site_url() . "/":get_permalink($this -> redirect_page_id);
            $order_id = $order_id.'_'.date("ymds");
            $checksum = $this -> getCheckSum($this -> merchant_id, $order -> order_total, $order_id, $redirect_url, $this -> working_key);
            $ccavenue_args = array(
                'Merchant_Id' => $this -> merchant_id,
                'Amount' => $order -> order_total,
                'Order_Id' => $order_id,
                'Redirect_Url' => $redirect_url,
                'Checksum' => $checksum,
                'billing_cust_name' => $order -> billing_first_name .' '. $order -> billing_last_name,
                'billing_cust_address' => $order -> billing_address_1,
                'billing_cust_country' => $order -> billing_country,
                'billing_cust_state' => $order -> billing_state,
                'billing_cust_city' => $order -> billing_city,
                'billing_zip' => $order -> shipping_postcode,
                'billing_cust_tel',
                'billing_cust_email' => $order -> billing_email,
                'delivery_cust_name' => $order -> shipping_first_name .' '. $order -> shipping_last_name,
                'delivery_cust_address' => $order -> shipping_address_1,
                'delivery_cust_country' => $order -> shipping_country,
                'delivery_cust_state' => $order -> shipping_state,
                'delivery_cust_tel' => '',
                'delivery_cust_notes' => '',
                'Merchant_Param' => '',
                'billing_zip_code' => $order -> billing_postcode,
                'delivery_cust_city' => $order -> shipping_city,
                'delivery_zip_code' => $order -> shipping_postcode);

            $ccavenue_args_array = array();
            foreach($ccavenue_args as $key => $value){
                $ccavenue_args_array[] = "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'/>";
            }
            return '<form action="'.$this -> liveurl.'" method="post" id="ccavenue_payment_form">
                ' . implode('', $ccavenue_args_array) . '
                <input type="submit" class="button-alt" id="submit_ccavenue_payment_form" value="'.__('Pay via CCAvenue', 'mrova').'" /> <a class="button cancel" href="'.$order->get_cancel_order_url().'">'.__('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'mrova').'</a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("body").block(
            {
                message: "<img src=\"'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Redirecting…\" style=\"float:left; margin-right: 10px;\" />'.__('Thank you for your order. We are now redirecting you to CCAvenue to make payment.', 'mrova').'",
                    overlayCSS:
            {
                background: "#fff",
                    opacity: 0.6
        },
        css: {
            padding:        20,
                textAlign:      "center",
                color:          "#555",
                border:         "3px solid #aaa",
                backgroundColor:"#fff",
                cursor:         "wait",
                lineHeight:"32px"
        }
        });
        jQuery("#submit_ccavenue_payment_form").click();

        });
                    </script>
                </form>';


        }


        /**
         *  CCAvenue Essential Functions
         **/
        private function getCheckSum($MerchantId,$Amount,$OrderId ,$URL,$WorkingKey)
        {
            $str ="$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$URL|$WorkingKey";
            $adler = 1;
            $adler = $this -> adler32($adler,$str);
            return $adler;
        }

        private function verifyCheckSum($MerchantId,$OrderId,$Amount,$AuthDesc,$CheckSum,$WorkingKey)
        {
            $str = "$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$AuthDesc|$WorkingKey";
            $adler = 1;
            $adler = $this -> adler32($adler,$str);

            if($adler == $CheckSum)
                return "true" ;
            else
                return "false" ;
        }

        private function adler32($adler , $str)
        {
            $BASE =  65521 ;

            $s1 = $adler & 0xffff ;
            $s2 = ($adler >> 16) & 0xffff;
            for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++)
            {
                $s1 = ($s1 + Ord($str[$i])) % $BASE ;
                $s2 = ($s2 + $s1) % $BASE ;
                //echo "s1 : $s1 <BR> s2 : $s2 <BR>";

            }
            return $this -> leftshift($s2 , 16) + $s1;
        }

        private function leftshift($str , $num)
        {

            $str = DecBin($str);

            for( $i = 0 ; $i < (64 - strlen($str)) ; $i++)
                $str = "0".$str ;

            for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++)
            {
                $str = $str."0";
                $str = substr($str , 1 ) ;
                //echo "str : $str <BR>";
            }
            return $this -> cdec($str) ;
        }

        private function cdec($num)
        {

            for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++)
            {
                $temp = $num[$n] ;
                $dec =  $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) - $n - 1);
            }

            return $dec;
        }
        /*
         * End CCAvenue Essential Functions
         **/
        // get all pages
        function get_pages($title = false, $indent = true) {
            $wp_pages = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order');
            $page_list = array();
            if ($title) $page_list[] = $title;
            foreach ($wp_pages as $page) {
                $prefix = '';
                // show indented child pages?
                if ($indent) {
                    $has_parent = $page->post_parent;
                    while($has_parent) {
                        $prefix .=  ' - ';
                        $next_page = get_page($has_parent);
                        $has_parent = $next_page->post_parent;
                    }
                }
                // add to page list array array
                $page_list[$page->ID] = $prefix . $page->post_title;
            }
            return $page_list;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Add the Gateway to WooCommerce
     **/
    function woocommerce_add_mrova_ccave_gateway($methods) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_Mrova_Ccave';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_mrova_ccave_gateway' );
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Programmatically access currency exchange rates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181990/programmatically-access-currency-exchange-rates) [how do I get currency exchange rates using Google Finance API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-using-google-finance-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a currency conversion API provided by a third party agency and wrap it into wordpress function.

[open exchange rates](http://openexchangerates.org/)

[XE Datafeed](http://www.xe.com/dfs/)

Please see the below example code using the google finance API.

```
//get the exchange rate from google finance
function get_exchange_rate($from='USD', $to='INR') {
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1%s=?%s";   //url for the currency convertor
    $result = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response = wp_remote_get(sprintf($url, $from, $to))); // fetches the result from the url
    if(is_wp_error( $response )) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $result = explode('"',$result);
    $result = str_replace(chr(160), '', substr( $result[3], 0, strpos($result[3], ' ') ) );
    return ( $result == 0 ) ? FALSE : $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Something like this? - http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=USD%3D%3FINR
Where to integrate this?